# ng-table fields that are object property

Tags: ngtable, object-property

I want a column in ng-table-dynamic that has a field which is an object property.

```
{
    field: 'customer.name',
    title: "Customer Name",
    show: true
    }
```

I tried lot of different way like

```
'customer.name'
'customer["name"]'
'customer[name]'
```

But none of this works.

Please help me out.
Thanks